# Update the row if a particular column value differ, else insert new row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, upsert

I have a table

```
UserId    Name    Age
1         Lisha   23
2         Ankur   21
3         Karan   22
```

For a particular given UserId, I want to update the age if the given age is different then the current age. Else if the UserId doesn't exists I want to insert a new row.

How can I do this in a single SQL statement.

Comment: INSERT INTO table (userid,name,age)
VALUES (3,karan,26) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE age =26;

Comment: Keyword for this operation, to search in Google, is UPSERT. You can also search for "Oracle MERGE equivalent in MYSQL". I don't know the answer but check these.

Comment: with an `insert on duplicate key update` statement, BUT the existence of unique index is critical. Without such a key in place, don't bother reading this

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a neat syntax that does exactly that, albeit it goes about it the opposite way - you define what you'd want to insert, and if a duplicate key error is generated, you define how you'd like to update the data instead:

```
INSERT INTO users
(userid, age)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE age = VALUES(age)
```

Comment: it is giving syntax error.
if i run this,
$sql = INSERT INTO  `user` (  `userid` ,  `name` ,  `age` ) VALUES ( 2,  'ankur', 23 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `age` =20
each time a new row is added.